# Use ImageWand component of ImageMagick lib with CMake

Tags: c, cmake, imagemagick, magickwand

I'm programming in C. I want use ImageMagick library but some fuction can't be resolved.

This is my cMakeList.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(WebServer)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")

set(SOURCE_FILES io.c server.c lock_fcntl.c sig_handler.c thread_job.c    msg_parser.c)
set(LIB http-parser-master/http_parser.c )

set(CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT true)
set(CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT ON)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS ImageWand)

include_directories(header)
include_directories(http-parser-master)

#include_directories(/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickWand)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(server ${SOURCE_FILES} ${LIB})
add_executable(client client.c io.c)
add_executable(main main.c io.c)

target_link_libraries(main ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(server Threads::Threads)
```

and this is the source main.c:

```
#include <ImageMagick-7/MagickWand/MagickWand.h>
#include "basic.h"

void convert_image(char *path, float quality_factor, char *out) {

    int width, height;
    MagickWand *n_wand = NULL;

    MagickWandGenesis();

    m_wand = (struct MagickWand *) NewMagickWand();


    MagickReadImage(m_wand,"logo:");

    width = MagickGetImageWidth(m_wand);
    height = MagickGetImageHeight(m_wand);

    if((width /= 2) < 1)width = 1;
    if((height /= 2) < 1)height = 1;

    MagickResizeImage(m_wand,width,height,LanczosFilter,1);

    MagickSetImageCompressionQuality(m_wand,95);

    MagickWriteImage(m_wand,"logo_resize.jpg");

   if(m_wand)m_wand = (struct MagickWand *) DestroyMagickWand(m_wand);

    MagickWandTerminus();
}
```

Only `MagickWandGenesis()` and `MagickWandTerminus()` are resolved.
The installation of the library ends correctly. How to solve?

edit:

Running I get the error:

```
/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickWand/MagickWand.h:29:40: fatal     error: MagickCore/magick-config.h: File o directory non esistente
 #  include "MagickCore/magick-config.h"
                                    ^
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o] Errore 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Errore 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/rule] Errore 2
make: *** [main] Errore 2
```

I tried the solution shown here but does not work:
[ImageMagick No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352640/imagemagick-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Please be more specific, you mean that the compiler tells you there are undefined references to these functions?

Comment: sorry, I have edited

Comment: `ImageMagick-7` should be apart of `${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS}`, so the main source should only have: `#include <MagickWand/MagickWand.h>`.

Comment: with `<MagickWand/MagickWand.h>` I obtain  `fatal error: MagickWand/MagickWand.h: File or directory not exist`
Only with `<MagickWand.h>` I get the same result described in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library structure is that:

```
ImageMagick-7
    ├── MagickCore
    │   ├── magick-config.h
    |
    └── MagickWand
        ├── MagickWand.h
```

`MagickWand.h` includes some header in MagickCore.
I fix replacing `include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})`
with `include_directories(/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7)`.
I don't know why but if i print `${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS}` this is not set.